# Turn this array into a matrix

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

Take a non-nested array as input. Turn it into a matrix by using the following method:

Let's say my array is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

First, I repeat that array 5 times: (the length)

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Then, I read it along the diagonals:

```
[[1],
 [2, 1],
 [3, 2, 1],
 [4, 3, 2, 1],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [5, 4, 3, 2],
 [5, 4, 3],
 [5, 4],
 [5]]
```

I flatten this array and split it into pieces of five (the length):

```
[[1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
 [1, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 5],
 [4, 3, 5, 4, 5]]
```

This is code golf. Fewest bytes wins.

Comment: Next time, please CAPITALIZE things.

Comment: How does this work if the original array has a length other than 5?

Comment: @ais523 I'm assumming its the same thing, you just replace 'five' with the length

Comment: Can we assume the numbers always be positive integers?

Comment: luis mendo- yes

Comment: oliver- yes that is correct

Comment: @JohnCena You shouldn't accept the first answer, you need to give the post some time to gain traction and some more answers.

Comment: How do you get that triangle by reading along the diagonals?

Comment: @PeterTaylor They are anti-diagonals, in a matrix sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 05AB1E, 13 bytes

```
.p¹.sR¦«í˜¹gä
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LnDCuS5zUsKmwqvDrcucwrlnw6Q&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVd)

Explanation:

```
                # Implicit input
 .p             # Get prefixes
   ¹            # Get first input
    .s          # Get suffixes
      R         # Reverse
       ¦        # Remove first element
        «       # Concatenate
         í      # Reverse every one
          ˜     # Flatten
           ¹gä  # Split into pieces of the length
                # Implicit print
```

Comment: don't you need to print it

Comment: and how did you request input

Comment: @JohnCena 05AB1E uses implicit input and output, so at the end, it will automatically print. At the start, there is nothing on the stack, so it asks for input.

Comment: Many of these golfing languages, such as 05AB1E, have built in default rules for requesting input and producing output, so that the programmer doesn't have to waste bytes on them.

Comment: The Output does not really match the desired output. It is no matrix and the numbers don't match.

Comment: @KarlNapf Oops, one sec

Comment: Well, it is a matrix, but the numbers are not correct (or tryitonline.net computes wrong)

Comment: You can fix the output by replacing `«˜` with `«í˜`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
WẋLŒDUṙLFsL
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=V-G6i0zFkkRV4bmZTEZzTA&input=&args=WzEsMiwzLDQsNV0&debug=on)

### Explanation

```
               Input: array z
WẋL            length(z) copies of z
   ŒD          Diagonals (starting with main diagonal)
     U         Reverse each
      ṙL       Rotate left length(z) places
               (now the top-left diagonal is in front)
        F      Flatten
         sL    Split into chunks of size length(z)
```

Comment: Hmm when I tried it with `L` it did weird stuff, hence I used the register :/ I just tried it again and it works... basically the same so I guess I shall just remove mine.

Comment: Of course Jelly has "diagonals" built in.... :)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>105</s> 96 bytes

-1 and -4 and -4 bytes thanks to Flp.Tkc

```python
a=input()
n=len(a)
L,M=[],[]
for i in range(n):L+=a[i::-1];M+=a[:i:-1]
print zip(*[iter(L+M)]*n)
```

The for loop adds the items like in the description, the real magic happens in the zip which is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124783/7082271)

Comment: sorry for the spam, but now that R is only used once, you can just put it there directly :P

Comment: @Flp.Tkc no problem, i am happy :)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6) 100 <s>101 105</s>

```js
a=>eval("for(u=r=[],i=l=a.length;i+l;i--)for(j=l;j--;v&&((u%=l)||r.push(s=[]),s[u++]=v))v=a[j-i];r")
```

*Less golfed*

```
a => {
  u = 0
  for(r=[], i=l=a.length; i+l>0; i--)
    for(j=l; j--; )
    {
      v = a[j-i]
      if (v) 
      {
        u %= l
        if (u==0) r.push(s=[])
        s[u++] = v
      }
    }
  return r
}
```

**Test**

```js
F=
a=>eval("for(u=r=[],i=l=a.length;i+l;i--)for(j=l;j--;v&&((u%=l)||r.push(s=[]),s[u++]=v))v=a[j-i];r")

function update() {
  var a=I.value.match(/\d+/g)
  if (a) {
    var r=F(a)
    O.textContent = r.join`\n`
  }
}

update()
```

```html
<input id=I value='1 2 3 4 5' oninput='update()'>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Wow, that's a very clever way to avoid the `return`. You should post a tip about that in the ES6 tip thread.

Comment: @ETHproductions it has a very narrow scope. Most of times, eval is better.

Comment: @ETHproductions indeed `eval` is better even *this* time :(

Comment: @ETHproductions I posted the tip, even if it's rarely useful, just in case

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
!Gg*tRwZRhPXzGne!
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=IUdnKnRSd1pSaFBYekduZSE&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNV0)

#### How it works

The following explanation uses input `[1 2 3 4 5]` as an example. To visualize the intermediate results, insert `%` (comment symbol) after any statement in the code.

Note that `;` is the row separator for matrices. So `[1 2]` is a row vector, `[1; 2]` is a column vector, and `[1 0; 0 1]` is the 2×2 identity matrix.

```
!     % Implicitly input a row vector. Transpose. Gives a column vector
      % STACK: [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
Gg    % Push input with all (nonzero) values replaced by ones
      % STACK: [1; 2; 3; 4; 5], [1 1 1 1 1]
*     % Multiply, with broadcast. Gives a square matrix
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 1;
                2 2 2 2 2;
                3 3 3 3 3;
                4 4 4 4 4;
                5 5 5 5 5]
tR    % Duplicate. Upper triangular part
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 1;
                2 2 2 2 2;
                3 3 3 3 3;
                4 4 4 4 4;
                5 5 5 5 5],
               [1 1 1 1 1
                0 2 2 2 2;
                0 0 3 3 3;
                0 0 0 4 4;
                0 0 0 0 5]
wZR   % Swap. Lower triangular part, below main diagonal 
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 1;
                0 2 2 2 2;
                0 0 3 3 3;
                0 0 0 4 4;
                0 0 0 0 5],
               [0 0 0 0 0;
                2 0 0 0 0;
                3 3 0 0 0;
                4 4 4 0 0;
                5 5 5 5 0]
h     % Concatenate horizontally
      % STACK: [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0;
                0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0;
                0 0 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0;
                0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 0 0;
                0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 0]
P     % Flip vertically
      % STACK: [0 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 0;
                0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 0 0;
                0 0 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0;
                0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0;
                1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
Xz    % Column vector of nonzeros, taken in column-major order
      % STACK: [1;2;1;3;2;1;4;3;2;1;5;4;3;2;1;5;4;3;2;5;4;3;5;4;5]
Gne   % Reshape into a matrix with as many rows as input size
      % STACK: [1 1 5 5 4;
                2 4 4 4 3;
                1 3 3 3 5;
                3 2 2 2 4;
                2 1 1 5 5]
 !    % Transpose. Implicitly display
      % STACK: [1 2 1 3 2;
                1 4 3 2 1;
                5 4 3 2 1;
                5 4 3 2 5;
                4 3 5 4 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 14 bytes

```
#($$&;</.)@#,:
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsU5ZQ0VFzdpGX0_TQVnHCiJ4006Ty89JT0EjGiLloKJZp6yjDBbTdVCOjVGzVgYJAzVwpSZn5CukKRjqKBjpKBjrKJjoKJhCTFmwAEIDAA)

- `#...#,:` Duplicate the input n times, where n is the input length.  We require `,:` to make the duplication work at the "row level" rather than the element level.
- `</.` Box every diagonal of the resulting n by n matrix.  J's `/.` does the heavy lifting here.
- `$$&;` Unbox that result `;` into a single list and reshape it `$` to the shape of duplicated input `$`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊏⍜♭⍏⊞+.⊃⇡▽⧻.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4oqP4o2c4pmt4o2P4oqeKy7iioPih6Hilr3ip7suCgpmIFsxIDIgMyA0IDVdCmYgWzFdCg==)

```
⊏⍜♭⍏⊞+.⊃⇡▽⧻.   input: vector V of length N
               ⧻.    keep V and push N
           ⊃⇡▽     consume both and push [0..N-1], V cycled N times
       ⊞+.          self outer product of range by addition
 ⍜♭⍏              flatten, replace the array with its sorting order, and
                     put it back into the same sized matrix
⊏                   for each number in the matrix, select the item at that index
                    in "V cycled N times"
```

The above is a slightly golfuscated version of the code below:

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍜∩♭'⊏⍏⊞+.⍏.↯⧻.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4o2c4oip4pmtKOKKj-KNjyniip4rLuKNjy7ihq_ip7suCgpmIFsxIDIgMyA0IDVdCmYgWzFdCg==)

```
⍜∩♭'⊏⍏⊞+.⍏.↯⧻.    input: a vector of integers of length N
               ↯⧻.     make the input a matrix by copying the input N times -> X
             ⍏         rise; sorting order of the rows (same as range N)
         ⊞+.           self outer product by addition -> Y
⍜∩♭          .        operate on X and Y flattened and assemble back..
    '⊏⍏                reorder elements of X by sorted order of elements of Y
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 116 bytes

```
a=>a.map(_=>b.splice(0,a.length),b=[].concat(...a.map((_,i)=>a.slice(~i)),...a.map((_,i)=>a.slice(0,~i))).reverse())
```

Well, it's a start...

Answer (score 1):

### R, 84 bytes

```
t(matrix(unlist(split(m<-t(matrix(rev(x<-scan()),l<-sum(1|x),l)),row(m)-col(m))),l))
```

Reads input from stdin and outputs/returns an R-matrix.

```
reversed_x <- rev(x<-scan())                # Read input from stdin and reverse
m <- t(matrix(reversed_x,l<-sum(1|x),l))    # Repeat and fit into matrix
diag_list <- split(m,row(m)-col(m))         # Split into ragged list of diagonals
t(matrix(unlist(diag_list),l))              # Flatten and transform back to matrix
```

**Explained**

The most interesting aspect about this answer is how the diagonals are retrieved. In general an object can be split up using the `split` function if supplied an object containing factors upon which the object is split into. To create these factors we can use `col` and `row` which return a matrix containing the column and row indices respectively. By taking the differences: `row(m)-col(m)` we get a matrix like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0   -1   -2   -3   -4
[2,]    1    0   -1   -2   -3
[3,]    2    1    0   -1   -2
[4,]    3    2    1    0   -1
[5,]    4    3    2    1    0
```

in which each diagonal is uniquely identified. We can now split based on this matrix and turn it into a ragged list by applying `split`:

```
$`-4`
[1] 1
$`-3`
[1] 2 1 
$`-2`
[1] 3 2 1
$`-1`
[1] 4 3 2 1
$`0`
[1] 5 4 3 2 1
$`1`
[1] 5 4 3 2
$`2`
[1] 5 4 3
$`3`
[1] 5 4
$`4`
[1] 5
```

(Note how the name of each vector correspond to the diagonal values in the matrix above).

The last step is just to flatten and turn it into a matrix of the form:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    1    3    2
[2,]    1    4    3    2    1
[3,]    5    4    3    2    1
[4,]    5    4    3    2    5
[5,]    4    3    5    4    5
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 110 bytes

```
n=a.size
b=[*(0...n)]
b.product(b).group_by{|i,j|i+j}.flat_map{|_,f|f.sort.map{|i,j|a[i][j]}}.each_slice(n).to_a
```

```
      #=> [[1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
      #    [1, 4, 3, 2, 1],
      #    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
      #    [5, 4, 3, 2, 5],
      #    [4, 3, 5, 4, 5]]
```

The `sort` operation may not be required, but the doc for Enumerable#group_by does not guarantee the ordering of values in the hash values (which are arrays), but current versions of Ruby provide the ordering one would expect and the ordering I would need if `sort` were removed from my code.

The steps are as follows.

```
n=a.size 
  #=> 5 
b=[*(0...n)]
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 
c = b.product(b)
  #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3],
  #    [1, 4], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2],
  #    [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 0], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]] 
d=c.group_by{|i,j|i+j}
  #=> {0=>[[0, 0]],
  #    1=>[[0, 1], [1, 0]],
  #    2=>[[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]],
  #    3=>[[0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0]],
  #    4=>[[0, 4], [1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4, 0]],
  #    5=>[[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1]],
  #    6=>[[2, 4], [3, 3], [4, 2]],
  #    7=>[[3, 4], [4, 3]],
  #    8=>[[4, 4]]} 
e=d.flat_map{|_,f|f.sort.map{|i,j|a[i][j]}}
  #=> [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5] 
f=e.each_slice(n)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2,
  #                  5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5]:each_slice(5)>
```

Lastly, `f.to_a` returns the array shown earlier.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 55 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.875 bytes

```
LẋÞ`f?Lẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiTOG6i8OeYGY/TOG6hyIsIiIsIlsxLDIsMyw0LDVdIl0=)

Bitstring:

```
0110000101111000101000101100100011000011001101100100000
```

```
LẋÞ`f?Lẇ­⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁢⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
# ‎⁡implicit input
Lẋ        # ‎⁢repeated [length] times
  Þ`      # ‎⁣antidiagonals
    f?Lẇ  # ‎⁤flatten and wrap in chunks the size of the length
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [Vyxal, 52 bits2, 6.5 bytes: `L~ẋÞ\`fẇ`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyI9IiwiIiwiTH7huovDnmBm4bqHIiwiIiwiWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDVdIl0=) ([vyncoded](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md))

Comment: oh what i was totally trying to do stack manipulation before giving up and just rereading the input

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 22 bytes

```
{x@l!s#,/=+/!s:2#l:#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qucMhRLFbW0bfV1lcstjJSzrFSrqjl4kpzMNRWNAUAky4INg==)

Comment: With @Bubbler’s idea to use grade becomes ```{s#x@l!<+/!s:2#l:#x}```.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 72 bytes

```ruby
->a,*r{t=[]
a.map{r+=t=[_1]+t}
r+=t while t.pop
[*r.each_slice(a.size)]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3PXTtEnW0iqpLbKNjuRL1chMLqou0bYG8eMNY7ZJaLhBHoTwjMydVoUSvIL-AK1qrSC81MTkjvjgnMzlVI1GvOLMqVTO2FmLe5gIFrbRohWhDHSMdYx0THdNYhViIzIIFEBoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 154 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9Na4QwFEX3/oq7TGhGxn5s4mSgy4JZla4GF69OlBQbh5gKrfjbbeKUUrp5cN8798EZG@ppHV7fTBOgyTrMWQZM1KOVYI/e0@fpyYVaHSs7htM2Uq45FFZSxzmxTlE@2i9TTuRRCa1@OcbLdvDMHnZ7hAFuV/C5UpWUMjZ62xi2F/am4Lk3k/GjycOQuqVW@g8TCeH@M0vJ0h9onnd@@LiYM4vMz20FzqbFe1Ri5LtR4uryHLx1Xc0lXpwN0WGOuldhimmDWCFwK3AncC/wwDfgEmuhd6xlxNNmyZb1Gw)

```scala
a=>{val n=a.size;var L,M=List[Int]();for(i<-0 to n-1){L=L:::a.slice(0,i+1).reverse.toList;M=M:::a.slice(i+1,n).reverse.toList};(L::: M).grouped(n).toList}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZAxa8MwEIV3/4o3SkQVSdouoh06FuypZAoZVEdxVRTZSJdAGvzb3bNjAoWO9@5770mXaxvsMLSf364mVNZHXAtg7w448iBsarLBW0r2sv2g5GOzkwab6AmvEwmcbYDlaYLESmGt8KjwpPAs70BkwOrgYkNfs5hQKlSslz6TdseOLtv3SLti2h/aBOHx8oAlTpE8R8i5EChHF4wxnJmDr51YKvjFSurkzi5lp6kdU2d8LKn@4MwqDvwP74v7o39817k9m8WtrJK6Se2JNcHe2TPRHV@GQhQ3x/jtvuiH4Rc)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val n = a.length
    var L, M = List.empty[Int]

    for (i <- 0 until n) {
      L = L ::: a.slice(0, i+1).reverse.toList
      M = M ::: a.slice(i+1, n).reverse.toList
    }

    val zipped = (L ::: M).grouped(n).toList

    println(zipped)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) (0.1.0), 20 bytes

```
↯~√⧻./⊐⊂≐(□↘)-⇡×2.⧻.
```

[Try it online](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=4oavfuKImuKnuy4v4oqQ4oqC4omQKOKWoeKGmCkt4oehw5cyLuKnuy4gWzEgMiAzIDQgNV0K)

### Explanation

```
                  ⧻. # (nondestructively) get array length
             -⇡×2.   # construct a range from len down to -len + 1
        ≐(□↘)        # for each element of the range, drop that many from the array
     /⊐⊂             # join all resulting arrays together
  √⧻.                # get square root of length, suppose we call it N...
↯~                   # ...then this reshapes the array to MxN, where M is inferred
```

Comment: It seems that the output is reversed? Adding `⇌` at the front seems to work. `≐(□↘)` can be shortened to `⊐≐↘`.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica 93 Bytes

```
Partition[Flatten[Table[If[i>n,#[[n;;(i-n+1);;-1]],#[[i;;1;;-1]]],{i,1,2(n=Length@#)-1}]],n]&
```

Here's how I'd ordinarily write this code (109 Bytes):

```
Partition[Reverse@Flatten[Table[Reverse@Diagonal[ConstantArray[Reverse@#,n],k],{k,-(n=Length@#)+1,n-1}]],n]&
```

This matrix plot gives a good idea from the structure due to a sequentially increasing input vector.

[image]

Here's the matrix plot with a random input vector. Obviously some structure still exists.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 92 bytes

```
n=NestList[#2,(r=Reverse)@#,(l=Length@#)-1]&;{Most@r[#~n~Rest],#~n~Most}~ArrayReshape~{l,l}&
```

Unnamed function taking a list as its argument. There might be other structures to such a function, but hopefully I golfed this structure pretty good....

The first part `n=NestList[#2,(r=Reverse)@#,(l=Length@#)-1]&` defines a function `n` of two arguments: the first is a list of length `l`, and the second is a function to apply to lists. `n` applies that function `l-1` times to the reversed argument list, saving all the results in its output list. (Defining `r` and `l` along the way is just golfing.)

`n` is called twice on the original list, once with the function being `Rest` (drop the first element of the list) and once with the function being `Most` (drop the last element). This produces all the desired sublists, but the whole list is there twice (hence the extra `Most`) and the first half is there in backwards order (hence the `r[...]`). Finally, `~ArrayReshape~{l,l}` forgets the current list structure and forces it to be an `l`x`l` array.

Answer (score 0):

**Mathematica, 85 bytes**

Literally performing the steps suggested:

```
(l=Length@#;Partition[Flatten@Table[Reverse@Diagonal[Table[#,l],i],{i,-l+1,l-1}],l])&
```

My gut says that there should be a clever way to use `Part` to do this shorter, but every attempt I've made has been longer than 85 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>9</s></sup> 8 bytes

```
CL¹Σ∂RL¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/39nn0M5zix91NAUBGf///4821DHSMdYx0TGNBQA)

-1 byte from Zgarb.

### Explanation

```
CL¹Σ∂*L¹;
       ¹  input(appends a ¹ to the end)
        ; enclosed
     *L   repeated length times
    ∂     antidiagonals
   Σ      flattened into a single list
C         cut into pieces of size
 L¹       of the length of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 60 bytes

```
Partition[Join@@Reverse[#~Drop~i]~Sum~{i,l=-Tr[1^#],-l},-l]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcO9CsMgEADgPa8hZDqH9GdMcejUKTTdxIIEQw@ihuu1i3ivbvvBFz2/QvSMi2/r2CZPjIw52VvGZMw9fAO9g1VypbwLOpk/UQrCNuoH2eGpHOit/ru@TYSJrdKX1SjXy7z4JKUrAxzgCCc41662Hw)