# Sum the diagonals

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix

Take a matrix of positive integers as input, and output the individual sums of the elements on the diagonal lines through the matrix.

You shall only count the lines that goes diagonally down and to the right. You must start with the diagonal that contains only the bottom-left element, then the length-two diagonal above that (if it exists) and so on through to the diagonal that contains only the top-right element, as illustrated below.

**Example:**

```
Input:
 8   14    5    1
10    5    5    8
 6    6    8   10
15   15    4   11

Output:
15, 21, 20, 32, 29, 13, 1
(Diagonals: {{15},{6,15},{10,6,4},{8,5,8,11},{14,5,10},{5,8},{1}})

Input:
1
Output:
1

Input: 
1 5
Output:
1, 5

Input:
4
1

Output: 
1, 4

Input:
17    4    5
24   16    5
 9   24   10
 1   14   22
 1   21   24
 4    4   17
24   25   17

Output:
24, 29, 22, 39, 47, 70, 43, 9, 5
```

Input and output formats are optional as always.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission in each language wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37958/34531)

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>53</s> 54 bytes

```
l=Length@#-1&;Tr@Diagonal[#,k]~Table~{k,-l@#,l@#&@@#}&
```

Pure function taking a 2D-array as input and returning a list. (Entries don't have to be integers or even numbers.) `Diagonal[#,k]` returns the `k`th diagonal above (or below, if `k` is negative) the main diagonal. `{k,-l@#,l@#&@@#}` computes the range of diagonals needed based on the dimensions of the input array. And `Tr` sums the entries of each diagonal.

Comment: Alternative at the same byte count, but maybe you can golf it further? Those parentheses look bad. `Tr@Diagonal[m,#]&/@Range@@({-1,1}(Dimensions[m=#]-1))&`

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```hs
z=0:z
foldl1$(.(++z)).zipWith(+).(0:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#lYpNCoAgFAb3neItWih@iA8yIvAcLcRFEJLQH9HKy5sdod0wMyU7M@Ymunhuy8at0EKpLKXO6ZrSswoltTCjLPucDnJ03el4qKVI3g/gDhYc4NlUsBgq9uhRi/lsjRYdmEMoP/8X) Usage: `(foldl1$(.(++z)).zipWith(+).(0:)) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`.

**Edit:** Thanks to  Ørjan Johansen for -3 bytes!

#### Ungolfed:

```hs
z = 0:z
s#t = zipWith(+)(0:s)(t++z)
f m = foldl1 (#) m
```

`z` is a list of infinitely many zeros. In `f` we fold over the list of lists `m` by combining two lists with the function `#`. In `#` the first list `s` contains  the accumulated column sums so far and the second list `t` is the new row which should be added. We shift `s` one element to the right by adding a zero to the front and element-wise add `s` and `t` with `zipWith(+)`. Because `s` might be arbitrarily large, we have to pad `t` with enough zeros by appending `z`.

Comment: That's shorter point-free: `foldl1$(.(++z)).zipWith(+).(0:)`.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>65</s> 58 bytes

```
a=>a.map(b=>b.map((c,i)=>r[i]=~~r[i]+c,r=[,...r]),r=[])&&r
```

Comment: 63-byte variant: `a=>a.map(r=>r.map(v=>s[i]=~~s[i++]+v,i=--y),s=[],y=a.length)&&s`

Comment: @Arnauld I agree, reversing was a bad move. But taking the length is too long too!

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
T&XdXs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@iFpESUfz/f7SFgqGJgqmCobWCoQGQNlWwsFYwA0KguAFQzBSETBQMDWMB) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#HUw5DsAgDNv7Ck@dSUSAirVPYEBCSB36g/5f1EG5HMfxs9rZ3/6tu61RIBEGqZDAaSgViUE@kDPPCJF5jF0w9siLL5knq1AKkoNrQ/9zV1UHyqQ@ukveWqVpnj8).

#### Explanation

```
T&Xd   % All diagonals of implicit input arranged as zero-padded columns
Xs     % Sum of each column. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Just curious: Do you think it would be better overall to have `s==sum(x(:))`, instead of sticking to the MATLAB convention, as MATL seems to do?

Comment: @StewieGriffin I have sometimes thought about that. My doubt was more between `sum(x)` and `sum(x,1)`. For a matrix `x`, the fact that `sum(x)` behaves differently if the matrix has 1 row is sometimes annoying. But in the end I decided to go with Matlab, so the two languages are closer; and add some `fun(x,1)` functions for the most common cases

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
0;+µ/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#TU7JDYQwDPynivkTidgKx4oCtogozfChGb40AJ3QSNZOAtnHSJ5TTm7pzqNP13av@zelYBACZgvyFhgEFK0BArnKFXPRMMqt0LyrOfEVkD5RFDEv/l268TJfl16fptKVTHZYd8bG8bHImnua5VfmxlnxLPv6y9T2eMg8mvgD)

#### How it works

```
0;+µ/  Main link. Argument: M (matrix / array of rows)

   µ   Combine all links to the left into a chain (arity unknown at parse time) and
       begin a new monadic chain.
    /  Reduce M by that chain. This makes the chain dyadic.
       Let's call the arguments of the chain L and R (both flat arrays).
0;         Prepend a 0 to L.
  +        Perform element-wise addition of the result and R.
           When the chain is called for the n-th time, R has n less elements, so
           the last n elements of L won't have matching elements in R and will be
           left unaltered.
```

Comment: Only the first R to reduce has one less element; it increases by one more element each row.

Comment: This is just clever... no `ŒD`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Once again, `ŒD`'s weird ordering prevented it from being useful.

Comment: @Dennis Then I think I'd make something that doesn't have so weird ordering... oh, maybe 3 monads *might* be incoming.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to Martin Ender

```
{_,({0\f+}*ee::m<:.+}
```

Anonymous block expecting the argument on the stack and leaves the result on the stack.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#K6z7Xx2vo1FtEJOmXauVmmpllWtjpadd@7@u4H90tKG5AhCYgAjTWK5oIxDL0AzGVbAEMiBiBiCuIYgF4hoZwbhGYMIExDWBGWVoDjPKyBTCjQUA)

**How it works**

```
_                   e# Duplicate the matrix
 ,(                 e# Get its length (# of rows) minus 1
   {0\f+}*          e# Prepend that many 0s to each row
          ee        e# Enumerate; map each row to [index, row]
            ::m<    e# Rotate each row left a number of spaces equal to its index
                :.+ e# Sum each column
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
Rvy¹gÅ0«NFÁ}})øO¨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x9UVnloZ/rhVoNDq/3cDjfW1moe3uF/aMX//9HRhuY6JjqmsTrRRiY6hmZglqUOiG0AZBnqGJroGBmBWUZAZAJkmQDVG5pDNBiZgpixAA)

**Explanation**

```
R                  # reverse input
 v                 # for each N,y (index, item)
  y¹gÅ0«           # pad y with as many zeroes as the number of rows in the input
        NFÁ}       # rotate each row N times right
            })     # wrap the result in a list
              øO   # sum the columns
                ¨  # remove the last element of the resulting list (the padded zeroes)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
+//.@|.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#U9JTT1OwtVJQV9BRMFCwAmJdPQXnIB0ft//a@vp6DjV6/zW5UpMz8hXSFEwUTFSU9NQV1LPyM/OKS4oy89JtrPXiDWutNHzcoNo1uRQsFBQUDE2AhIIpiDDkMjSAc8CEBZeCGYgGE2DVBlyGIBkwoQDSamjIpfkfAA)

This is pretty simple:

```
+//.@|.
+/        sum
  /.      on oblique lines
    @|.   on the reversed array
```

Oblique reversed lines are the diagonals of the array, so this is just summing the diagonals.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda M:reduce(lambda x,y:map(sum,zip([0]+x,y+[0]*len(x))),M)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#bU/LCoMwELznK/aY1ByS4KtCP8EvSHOwVUFQEVvB9uftrkak4GFIZrIzs6nhBvelLbpHWUCejVU5PSvu@Sw/WVcM/DV18tsM3CoXoBbgeWmrns9CCJmLZRib/g01Z2AtpBJ0KAEihHaSAVitPCekmwYx3gk0r/wcvhMA/Vo7xwRjf9mnGuWe6KHvOfHoZOtA3zpjqC8@OFwlrJraM7Y/GXNwQ9g7Qr9zcuSZaOXYvfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒDS€ṙZL$
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390kkvwo6Y1D3fOjPJR@f//f3S0obmOgomOgmmsDpdCtJGJjqEZjKNgqQPiG0A4hjqGJjpGRjCOERCZQDgmIAMMzWEGGJmCOLEA)**

Half of the code is used to put the results into the correct order.

#### How?

```
ŒDS€ṙZL$ - Main link: list of lists of numbers
ŒD       - diagonals (starts with the diagonal containing the top left element,
         -            then the next diagonal to the right, and so on wrapping around)
  S€     - sum €each
       $ - last two links as a monad
     Z   - transpose the matrix
      L  - length (width of the matrix)
    ṙ    - rotate the results left by that amount
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 47 bytes

```pl
map{$j=--$.;map{@a[$j++]+=$_}split}<>
print"@a"
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 45 bytes

Unnamed function taking a matrix-class object as input:

```
function(x)sapply(split(x,col(x)-row(x)),sum)
```

Using the idea explained in  [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100958/56989) answer.

Comment: I believe the rules in this challenge allow for you to get rid of the call to `unname`, but this is an awesome solution regardless!

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 71 bytes

Assuming A is a matrix, for example:

```
A = [17 4 5;24 16 5; 9 24 10; 1 14 22; 1 21 24; 4 4 17;24 25 17];
```

Then we have:

```
[m,n]=size(A);
a=[zeros(m,m-1),A]';
for i=1:m+n-1
trace(a(i:end,:))
end
```

Notice that transposing the matrix reverses the ordering of the diagonal sums, which saved an overall two bytes in the for loop.

Output:

```
ans =  24
ans =  29
ans =  22
ans =  39
ans =  47
ans =  70
ans =  43
ans =  9
ans =  5
```

Comment: `[m,n]=size(A);for i=1:m+n-1,trace([zeros(m-1,m);A'](i:end,:)),end` saves 6 bytes. Octave can do direct indexing and inline assignments. Unfortunately, assuming that a variable exist in the work space prior to running the code is not allowed, so I think you must use `input`, like [this](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#FYrBCsMgEER/ZW8qsdAV01AXD/kO8VBSCx40xaSX/LxdYeA9ZqaHomv0R76SXH2u398phVCKPnuD7NGVqd5Qn@21JRmu1PZDFi6KolVEmV2qb@2U0szeAy5gYSZjAR9MeMLQOwECWjBmiOFY4h8vy7iamSXSHw) bringing it back up to 75 bytes. Nice approach though, so +1 from me :) And welcome to PPCG! =)

Comment: Also, `zeros(m-1,m)` can be written `~e(m-1,m)`, saving 4 bytes :) Neat huh?

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ÞD?L‹ǔṠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnkQ/TOKAuceU4bmgIiwiIiwiW1sxNywgNCwgNV0sIFsyNCwgMTYsIDVdLCBbOSwgMjQsIDEwXSwgWzEsIDE0LCAyMl0sIFsxLCAyMSwgMjRdLCBbNCwgNCwgMTddLCBbMjQsIDI1LCAxN11dIl0=)

Takes 4 bytes to get it in the right order. If the order didn't matter, it would be 3 bytes (remove the `?L‹ǔ`).

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 126 bytes

```
x=input()
f=lambda k:[x[i+k][i]for i in range(len(x)-k)]
a=map(f,range(4)[::-1])
x=zip(*x)
print(map(sum,a+map(f,range(1,4))))
```

`f` only works on the lower triangular section, so I transpose it and get the upper triangular section that way. Don't know why the `f` function doesn't work for negative values (I changed `f` to be shorter because the part to get the negatives didn't work).

Comment: I get an error for the last test case. https://tio.run/nexus/python2#TctBCsMgEAXQvaeYpTYGqpiGBjyJuLA0KUMSKzYB6eVTTVPowMB/zPwtafRhXSgjg57cfLs7GDuTDFajNWiHZwQE9BCdf/R06j1NrB6ZJU7PLtCBfw@Kma6rhWUk6TcGekqMhIh@oeXrtc7cVf//giuWZ9uMES0HxaGxHIzMQVwOXDnsPheIHDKkPCDLqgK110X768tml/0A

Answer (score 0):

## C, 148 bytes

[**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/oRcerv)

```c
s;g(int i,int j,int**m,int x){for(s=0;x;x--)s+=m[i++][j++];printf(" %d",s);}
k;f(int n,int**m){for(k=n;--k;)g(k,0,m,n-k);for(;k<n;k++)g(0,k,m,n-k);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 81 Bytes

Take Input as 2 D Array

```
<?foreach($_GET as$k=>$v)foreach($v as$x=>$y)$r[$x-$k]+=$y;ksort($r);print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUol3dw2xjY620DE00THVMYzl0ok2NACyTHUsQGwzHTMdoJwBWBwob6pjomNoGBtr/T8tvyg1MTlDA2yCQmKxSratnUqZJly4DCRWARSr1FQpilap0FXJjtW2Vam0zi7OLyrRUCnStC4oyswriS8Cs///BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Awk, 67 Bytes

```
{for(f=0;f++<NF;)s[NF-NR+f]+=$f}END{i=0;while(i++<NR*2)print s[i]}
```

Ungolfed:

```
{
    for (f = 0; f++ < NF;)
        s[NF-NR+f] += $f
}
END {
    i = 0
    while (i++ < NR*2)
        print s[i]
}
```

Awk splits on whitespace `$n` is the `n`th field (1-indexed); `NF` is the number of fields on the line, `NR` is the number of the current row. Undefined variables are 0 and created on first use.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 86 bytes

a memory friendly solution in two variants:

```php
<?for($i=$c=count($a=$_GET);--$i>-$c;print$s._)for($s=0,$d=$c;$d--;)$s+=$a[$i+$d][$d];
<?for($i=$c=count($a=$_GET);--$i>-$c;print$s._)for($s=$d=0;$d<$c;)$s+=$a[$i+$d][$d++];
```

takes input from script parameters, uses underscore as delimiter;
use default settings (not default php.ini) or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d0eacededdc003bc00054e0805c2dae98177eb8)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 81 bytes

```
#(apply map +(map(fn[i c](concat(repeat(-(count %)i 1)0)c(repeat i 0)))(range)%))
```

Quite verbose, as it pads lists with zeros so that we can just calculate the column-wise sum.

Answer (score 0):

### mathematica 73 bytes

```
Plus@@@Table[Diagonal[Partition[#1,#2[[1]]],k],{k,-#2[[2]]+1,#2[[1]]-1}]&
```

This one works for ANY 2D-array m x n  (not only nxn)
input the array at the end of the code like this (the last test case)

```
[{17,4,5,24,16,5,9,24,10,1,14,22,1,21,24,4,4,17,24,25,17},{3,7}]
```

> {24, 29, 22, 39, 47, 70, 43, 9, 5}

input in form [{a,b,c,d...},{m,n}]

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage)

```
mΣ∂m↔T
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fc4kcdTbmP2qaE/P//PzraQsfQRMdUxzBWJ9rQAMgw1bEAMs10zHSAMgYgUaCkqY6JjqFhbCwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
     T  # Transpose the (implicit) argument; swapping rows/columns
   m↔   # Reverse each row
  ∂     # Take the anti-diagonals of this matrix
mΣ      # And sum each inner anti-diagonal list
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```