# Check if a matrix is a Toeplitz matrix

Tags: code-golf, grid, decision-problem, matrix

You will be given a two-dimensional array and a number and you are asked to find whether the given matrix is [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) or not. A matrix is a Toeplitz matrix if every descending diagonal, going from left to right, has only one distinct element. That is, it should be in the form:

[image: Form]

### Input Format:

You will be given a function which will take `two-dimensional` matrix as argument.

### Output Format:

Return `1` from the function if the matrix is **Toeplitz**, else return `-1`.

### Constraints:

```
3 < n,m < 10,000,000
```

where `n` is the number of rows while `m` will be the number of columns.

### Sample Test Case:

```
Sample Input :
4 
5
6 7 8 9 2
4 6 7 8 9
1 4 6 7 8
0 1 4 6 7 

Sample Output : 
1
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: This is a good challenge, but we prefer laxer I/O requirements here. I'd suggest allowing both programs and functions [as is the default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/20260). And to allow True/False or 1/0 as outputs, or perhaps just any two consistent distinct outputs as seems to be [preferred](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12307/20260) for decision problems.

Comment: Also, a definition of Toeplitz would be good, as would be more test cases including non-Toeplitz ones. Not sure what you mean about adding code.

Comment: I think you must reduce the maximum value of **n,m**. Otherwise the main part of this challenge is to find a way to process a 1 terabyte matrix.

Comment: Will the matrix elements always be non-negative integers?

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
2Boole[#==ToeplitzMatrix[#&@@@#,#&@@#]]-1&
```

Mathematica doesn't have a built-in to check whether something is a Toeplitz matrix, but it does have a built-in to generate one. So we generate one from the first column (`#&@@@#`) and the first row (`#&@@#`) of the input and check whether it's equal to the input. To convert the `True`/`False` result to `1`/`-1` we use `Boole` (to give `1` or `0`) and then simply transform the result with `2x-1`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 30 bytes

I'm assuming I don't have to handle 1,000,000x1,000,000 matrices as it says in the challenge. This works for matrices that don't exceed the available memory (less than 1 TB in my case).

```matlab
@(x)x==toeplitz(x(:,1),x(1,:))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7PV09P776BRoVlha1uSn1qQk1lSpVGhYaVjqKlToWGoY6Wp@b9CwTbaTMFcwULBUsGIy0QByuYyVICyuQwUoOxYay6uzDSFNKCBOgopmcUFGuohRaWp6prWCqk5xalQIbdEIFtdUyc1L@U/AA)

This takes a matrix `x` as input and creates a Toeplitz matrix based on the values on the first column, and the first row. It will then check each element of the matrices for equality. IF all elements are equal then the input is a Toeplitz matrix.

The output will be a matrix of the same dimensions as the input. If there are any zeros in the output then that's considered falsy be Octave.

**Edit:**

Just noticed the strict output format:

This works for 41 bytes. It might be possible to golf off a byte or two from this version, but I hope the output rules will be relaxed a bit.

```matlab
@(x)2*(0||(x==toeplitz(x(:,1),x(1,:))))-1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ŒDE€Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390kovro6Y1D3ct@P//f3S0mY65joWOpY5RrA6XQrSJDpQP5hnqQPlgnoEOlB8bCwA)

Following the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).

```
ŒDE€Ạ
ŒD     all diagonals
   €   for each diagonal ...
  E       all elements are equal
    Ạ  all diagonal return true
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
Œ2ùvy`¦s¨QP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390ktHhnWWVCYeWFR9aERjw/390tJmOuY6FjqWOUayOQrSJDpQL4hjqQLkgjoEOlBsbCwA)

**Explanation**

```
Œ             # get all sublists of input
 2ù           # keep only those of length 2
   v          # for each such pair
    y`        # split to separate lists
      ¦       # remove the first element of the second list
       s¨     # remove the last element of the first list
         Q    # compare for equality
          P   # product of stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:t)|init a==tail b=f$b:t|1>0= -1
f _=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#Rcq9CsIwEADgvU9xQ4cWrqUR8SeQ7s6OIchVk3qgEeKBS989li5ZP743cTQcxSe6S/19fn596Jvk6aH1VRLHuRutvaxh9sm5NoeG9KSlXTiyABkjxC@YTKhXXdQ4GOhUFeBmVM7WHhCOCCeEM8LOYQV2j1BwE4VQcJMBoaBzfw)

Comment: Dang, overcomplicating it again. Curiously, I get that down to 39 bytes with truthy/falsy output, so if Toeplitz = `False` were allowed I might have beaten it by one byte.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 94 bytes

```
l=Length;If[l@Flatten[Union/@Table[#~Diagonal~k,{k,-l@#+1,l@#[[1]]-1}]]==l@#+l@#[[1]]-1,1,-1]&
```

input

> {{6, 7, 8, 9, 2}, {4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {1, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 4, 6,
>      7}}

another one based on **Stewie Griffin**'s algorithm

### Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
If[#==#[[;;,1]]~ToeplitzMatrix~#[[1]],1,-1]&
```

Comment: Do you need to define `s`? Can't you just use `#` instead?

Comment: yes! you are right!

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>239</s> <s>233</s> <s>220</s> 113 bytes

```
int c(int[][]a){for(int i=a.length,j;i-->1;)for(j=a[0].length;j-->1;)if(a[i][j]!=a[i-1][j-1])return -1;return 1;}
```

-107 bytes after a tip of using a more efficient algorithm thanks to *@Neil*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#pY7BasMwDIbvfQrtZoMS6jG6DdO9wU49Gh@8NO0UUqckykoJfvZMzcx2HtVB@sUHH3/VhmGA90BxmikyVEq2884HPR26/vYBbUPZ1vHIn9hYKoo3Y/WNNdvg1j4j2/wAOqjgyLvGPwimwkiUpfuaxz5CYWxOxqYZ4Dx@tFTBwIHlfHW0h5OUUTvuKR6dB@mxApnddeD6VHYjl2dB3EYV68vSXOmyWp5cffrN0waf8QVf8THhYvnP/FmeMHvushjMnrssa8yelLS2IkqrNH8D)

```
int c(int[][]a){                // Method with integer-matrix parameter and integer return-type
  for(int i=a.length,j;i-->1;)  //  Loop over the rows (excluding the first)
    for(j=a[0].length;j-->1;)   //   Loop over the columns (excluding the first)
      if(a[i][j]!=a[i-1][j-1])  //    If the current cell doesn't equal the one top-left of it:
        return -1;              //     Return -1
                                //   End of columns loop (implicit / single-line body)
                                //  End of rows loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return 1;                     //  Return 1
}                               // End of method
```

Comment: what is r & c in first function?

Comment: @MickeyJack Rows and columns (`r` = `n` and `c` = `m` if you compare it to the challenge).

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the array as a parameter to the function? Also, there is a much more efficient algorithm for this, which would cut your byte count by about 50%.

Comment: @Neil Well, it saves 13 bytes to put it on class-level instead, and you'll still have to set the array before calling the method (which can be seen in the TIO). I believe this is an allowed rule regarding code-golf, but I'll see if I can find a meta-post as confirmation. As for the more efficient algorithm: I'm sure there is, but which one are you talking about?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Simply check that all elements not in the first row or column equal the element diagonally up and left from it.

Comment: @Neil Ah of course. It's obvious now that you say it, but still brilliant. Thanks, it indeed halved the byte-count.

Comment: Ah, you even got to use the `-->` operator!

Comment: @Neil Always a useful operator to use. And I also like the `+++` or `---` operators in Java, which I unfortunately haven't used in this answer. ;p

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 51 bytes

`t` takes a list of lists of integers and returns an integer.

```hs
t m=1-sum[2|or$zipWith((.init).(/=).tail)=<<tail$m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#RcqxCsIwEIDh3ae4IUMC12iLaC2Nu7ODQ8gQNLQHJpX0RBDfvWqXTj98/NFTMpQ4ZH9lMfbDS7OWOfhb05w5U@qKo7Wn39CF7JyaGKIpi/EZbfUZsnjT40LcS6kpESst10Zp9nRXpm3/FdFNk7U7hD1CjXBAqByuwG4RFpylRFhwlg3Cgs59AQ)

This could have been 39 or 38 bytes with truthy/falsy output.

The idea to use `init` was inspired by Emigna's 05AB1E answer, which uses a very similar method; before that I used a nested zipping.

## How it works

- `zipWith((.init).(/=).tail)=<<tail` is a point-free form of
  `\m->zipWith(\x y->tail x/=init y)(tail m)m`.
- This combines each consecutive pair of rows of `m`, checking if the first with first element removed is different from the second with second element removed.
- The `or` then combines the checks for all pairs of rows.
- `1-sum[2|...]` converts the output format.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
ΛE∂↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9xs10cdTY/apvz//z862kzHXMdCx1LHKFYn2kQHygOyDXWgPCDbQAfKi40FAA)

[-2 bytes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55721763#55721763) from Zgarb.

My first Husk answer! (Language Of The Month)

Takes matrix as command line argument.

Returns length of longest diagonal for true, and 0 otherwise.

### Explanation

```
ΛE∂↔
   ↔ reverse the rows
  ∂  get antidiagonals
Λ    Check if all elements satisfy condition:
 E   Are all the elements equal?
```

Comment: 3 days to learn a completely new golfing language?  Pretty darn good!

Comment: Nothing is impossible with the power of well written tutorials and surprisingly convenient builtins @DominicvanEssen

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>65</s> 54 bytes

```
a=>a.some((b,i)=>i--&&b.some((c,j)=>c-a[i][j-1]))?-1:1
```

Comment: Or [using your own trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120148/58563): `a=>a.some(b=>b.some((v,i)=>d[i]-(d[i]=v),d=[,...d]),d=[])?-1:1` (62 bytes)

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks, but it turns out I was over-thinking the problem again...

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 54 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,m{m.reduce{|x,y|x[0..-2]==y[1,b]?y:[]}.size<=>1}
```

Exactly as specified, can be golfed more if flexible input/output is accepted.

### Explanation:

Iterate on the matrix, and compare each line with the line above, shifted by one to the right. If they are different, use an empty array for the next iteration. At the end, return -1 if the final array is empty, or 1 if it's at least 2 elements (since the smallest possible matrix is 3x3, this is true if all comparisons return true)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2uXqJOkk1udq1eUmlKanFpdU6FTWVMRbaCnp2sUa2tbGW2okxRrX2kVHVurV5xZlWpja2dY@79AIS3aWMdYJxoobaRjHKsD5AFZQBrI0zGMjY3lwq/EBKjkPwA)

Comment: Nice use of `<=>` to compute the result!

Comment: How about `|(*x,_),y|` so you don't need to slice `x`?

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 70 bytes

```
<?=!preg_match('/\[([\d,]+?),\d+\],\[\d+,(?!\1)/',json_encode($_GET));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 108

```
r=range
f=lambda x,n,m:all([len(set([x[i][j] for i in r(n) for j in r(m) if j-i==k]))==1 for k in r(1-n,m)])
```

Not efficient at all since it touches every element `n+m` times while filtering for diagonals. Then checks if there are more than one unique element per diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 121 bytes

```
f(m)==(r:=nrows(m);c:=ncols(m);for i in 1..r-1 repeat for j in 1..c-1 repeat if m(i,j)~=m(i+1,j+1)then return false;true)
```

m has to be a Matrix of some element that allow ~=; ungolf it

```
f m ==
  r := nrows(m)
  c := ncols(m)
  for i in 1..(r - 1) repeat
    for j in 1..(c - 1) repeat
      if m(i,j)~=m(i + 1,j + 1)     then return(false)
  true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 48 bytes

```r
pryr::f(all(x[-1,-1]==x[-nrow(x),-ncol(x)])*2-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclNCoAgEEDhfSeZiRloIvqBPEm0CEEISkGM9PQm2O7jPZ/Nytk8VofTWYh4XBfEjYVYdqWKrHdv6cRWu7Jwx7ZnyWnl@wj@jKBhpIGEOpqoav61/OqrkAZsUmMgYf4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 148 bytes

```
m(1`\d+
$*#
1`#\n\d+\n
@
+`(#*)#@([^#\n]*(#*)\n)(.*)$
$1# $2$1@$4 #$3
@

+`##
# #
+(+s`^(\d+)\b(.*)^\1\b
$1$2#
s`.*^\d.*^\d.*
-1
)%`^[^- ]+ ?

\s+
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LYxLCoRADET3dYpAMtAflInT81uN9zA2jbgdN94fbaE3xavwUsffabE1QgJDC9tWi20YEYvj4Hl0U67XOVzNNu/64AWiTDKIjpKI5VH16jODiRFd3Et2dcfbcunZ1Jb6IgNjL33ItrZAp/C3kqfc0RzpB9geoceR8MSL3vShLw1I1BhKjXGnxic)

An N×M input matrix

```
6 7 8 9 2 0
4 6 7 8 9 2
1 4 6 7 8 9
0 1 4 6 7 8
```

is first converted to an N×(N+M-1) matrix by aligning the diagonals this way:

```
# # # 6 7 8 9 2 0
# # 4 6 7 8 9 2 #
# 1 4 6 7 8 9 # #
0 1 4 6 7 8 # # #
```

and then the first column is repeatedly checked to contain a single unique number, and removed if this is so. The matrix is Toeplitz iff the output is blank.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work with negative numbers, gotta fix this :)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
T&Xd"@Xz&=v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D9ELSJFySGiSs227H8sl716SVFpSUalOletelpiTnEqkBXrEvI/2kzBXMFCwVLByNpEAcq2NlSAsq0NFKDsWK5oXUOilaqnpaaqWyuop2UqgKl8CFWaqw6SLMlPLcjJLKkCiSVCOSB2MZQDYmdDOeqxAA)

The straightforward "construct a Toeplitz matrix and check against it" method, that the top few answers use, somehow felt boring to me (and [it looks like](https://matl.suever.net/?code=t1Z%29y1Y%29%26YT%3D&inputs=%5B%27mice%27%3B%27emic%27%3B%27nemi%27%5D&version=20.9.1) that would be 1 byte longer anyway). So I went for the "check each diagonal only contains one unique value" method.

`T&Xd` - Extract the diagonals of the input and create a new matrix with them as columns (padding with zeros as needed)

`"` - iterate through the columns of that

`@Xz` - push the iteration variable (the current column), and remove (padding) zeros from it

`&=` - [broadcast equality check](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/8774) - this creates a matrix with all 1s (truthy) if all the remaining values are equal to one another, otherwise the matrix contains some 0s which is falsy

`v` - concatenate result values together, to create one final result vector which is either truthy (all 1s) or falsey (some 0s)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I *think* this is right.

```
äÏÅeX¯JÃ×
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=5M/FZVivSsPX&input=W1s2LDcsOCw5LDJdLCBbNCw2LDcsOCw5XSwgWzEsNCw2LDcsOF0sIFswLDEsNCw2LDddXQ)

```
äÏÅeX¯JÃ×     :Implicit input of 2D-array
ä             :Consecutive pairs
 Ï            :Reduced by
  Å           :  Slice the first element off the second array
   e          :  Check for equality with
    X         :    First array
     ¯J       :    Slice off the last element
       Ã      :End reduce
        ×     :Reduce by multiplication
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 94 bytes

```
#(if(=(+ %2 %3 -1)(count(set(for[Z[zipmap][i r](Z(range)%)[j v](Z(range)r)][(- i j)v]))))1 -1)
```